# Maven and Ant Oddness

Tags: maven-2

I'm trying to use the maven-antrun-plugin to get ant to generate some code for me (wsdlc with WebLogic but this isn't particularly pertinent).

I've passed maven.compile.classpath to the plugin by doing:

in the pom.xml, but when I do:

Compile classpath: ${compile_classpath}

in the build.xml I'm getting:

Compile classpath: ${compile_classpath}

which suggests it hasn't been set.

I've tried adding:

to the pom by way of debug, this gives:

Compile classpath: ${maven.compile.classpath}

which suggests it's not set there either (though I'm not convinced this is the correct thing to do anyway).

Any idea appreciated.

Regards,

Nick

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore this, the problem was caused by a combination of ignorance and typos.

Should anyone want to display the classpath in the pom you need to do something like:

```
<property name="compile_classpath" refid="${maven.compile.classpath}"/>
<echo message="Compile classpath: $compile_classpath"/>
```